# Android onTouch event not occurring?

Tags: java, android, textview, ontouchlistener

I have been researching and struggling with my code to get a textview to update the score when a "ghost" is touched.

This is my first Android application and so far as i can tell(i added Log.w() to the ontouch but a log is never posted as well as the score not being incremented or even appearing) the onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) is never called. Below is my code.

```
package com.cs461.Ian;

//TODO:Add accelerometer support
//TODO:Add Clickable ghosts
//TODO:Add camera background
/*Completed:(As of 2:30am 4/16)
 * Activity launches
 * Ghost appears on screen
 * Ghost will randomly move around the screen
 */

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

Bitmap g;
Ghost a;
Ghost still;
SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
boolean firsttime=true;
int draw_x,draw_y,xSpeed,ySpeed,score=0;
TextView t;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    a = new Ghost(getApplicationContext());
    still = new Ghost(getApplicationContext());
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    a.Initalize(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ghost), 20, 20);
    still.Initalize(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ghost), 120, 120);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
    t.setText("TEST SCORE TO SEE IF TEXTVIEW SHOWS UP");

    a.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                score++;
                t.setText("Score: "+score);

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    still.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                score++;
                t.setText("Score: "+score);
                Log.w("CLICKED","Clicked on ghost "+score+" times");

            }
            return true;
        }
    });



    setContentView(new Panel(this));
}


class Panel extends View {
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //g.Initalise(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/res/drawable-hdpi/ghost.png"), 200, 150, 5, 5);;
        update(canvas);
        invalidate();
    }

    /*Places ghost on screen and bounces it around in the screen. My phone is apparently only API level 4(the most up to date is 15) so i didn't code it
     *for the accelerometer yet.
     */
    public void update(Canvas canvas) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        if(firsttime){
            draw_x = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (this.getWidth()*2)) ;
            draw_y = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (this.getHeight()*2)) ;
            xSpeed = rand.nextInt(10);
            ySpeed = rand.nextInt(10);

            firsttime=false;
        }
         draw_x+=xSpeed;
         draw_y+=ySpeed;
        draw_x = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (this.getWidth()*2)) ;
        draw_y = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (this.getHeight()*2)) ;
         if (draw_x>this.getWidth()){
          draw_x = (this.getWidth()*2)-draw_x;
          xSpeed = rand.nextInt(10);
          if(xSpeed >=5)
              xSpeed=-xSpeed;
         }
         if (draw_y>this.getHeight()){
          draw_y = (this.getHeight()*2)-draw_y;
          ySpeed = rand.nextInt(10);
          if(ySpeed >=5)
              ySpeed=-ySpeed;
         }
         g = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ghost);
         canvas.drawBitmap(g, draw_x, draw_y, null);
         still.draw(canvas);
         a.update(canvas);


        }
    }


}
```

Forgot to add class Ghost:

```
package com.cs461.Ian;

import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class Ghost extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{
public Ghost(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private Bitmap mAnimation;
private int mXPos;
private int mYPos;
private Rect mSRectangle;
private int mSpriteHeight;
private int mSpriteWidth;
View v;
Rect dest;
int score = 0;

/*public Ghost() {
    mSRectangle = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    mXPos = 80;
    mYPos = 200;
}*/



public void Initalize(Bitmap theBitmap, int Height, int Width) {
    mSRectangle = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
    mXPos = 80;
    mYPos = 200;
    mAnimation = theBitmap;
    mSpriteHeight = Height;
    mSpriteWidth = Width;
    mSRectangle.top = 0;
    mSRectangle.bottom = mSpriteHeight;
    mSRectangle.left = 0;
    mSRectangle.right = mSpriteWidth;
    dest = new Rect(mXPos, mYPos, mXPos + mSpriteWidth,
            mYPos + mSpriteHeight);

}
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {


    canvas.drawBitmap(mAnimation, mXPos, mYPos, null);
}

public void update(Canvas canvas) {
    new Random();

    mXPos = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (canvas.getWidth()*2)) ;
    mYPos = Math.round(System.currentTimeMillis() % (canvas.getHeight()*2)) ;
    if (mXPos>canvas.getWidth())
      mXPos = (canvas.getWidth()*2)-mXPos;
    if (mYPos>canvas.getHeight())
      mYPos = (canvas.getHeight()*2)-mYPos;

     draw(canvas);


}

public Rect getRect() {
    return mSRectangle;
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    score++;
    //CameraActivity.t.setText("Score: "+CameraActivity.score);
    Log.w("CLICKED","Clicked on ghost "+score+" times");
    return true; //doesn't work if returns false either
}


}
```

Comment: If the click function is always the same, why not just put it into the class definition for the ghost in the constructor?

Comment: What happens if you move the Log.w outside the action if block?

Comment: In the ghost constructor add this.setClickable(true);

Comment: @JustinDanielson, that is unnecessary as the setOnTouchListener() call will ensure that it is set to be clickable. +1 to moving to the class definition, unless of course it is testing for now to be more complicated later.

Comment: @R.daneel.olivaw if i move Log.w outside/add a new one it logs it into the logcat as it should.

Comment: @Jared Its mostly because ive been building one thing at a time and expanding as i go. Planning a big cleanup once i get the touch working

Comment: @SnakeMan2058 Got it. I am working in a similar manner as I learn some components that are very new to me so I can certainly understand the thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` in your `Activity` to handle all the touch events that may occur.  Return `false` to pass down the `MotionEvent` to the next view\layout in the hierachy if they they handle events.

Comment: I overrode it to simply return false every time, however it still does nothing. I had sort of assumed it would think every touch was on the ghost but i guess i was mistaken. I have to go to one of my classes now but i will return in a few hours

Comment: Can you explain the idea behind the game?  Also I see `Ghost` extends `Button`.  You can extend `View` and still have `Ghost` clickable/touchable.  My thoughts of overriding `dispatchTouchEvent` was that all interaction would be done through that and you wouldn't need to pass down any events but it does all depend on what you want to achieve.

Comment: At the moment all i want is for my textView to increment when the ghost is touched.

Comment: Ok for something like that I would create `Ghost` by extending `View` and implementing `View.OnTouchListener`.  When it has detected it has been touched increment the `TextView` text in your `Activity` by doing something like `((MyActivity)context).textView.getText()...`.  (You will probably need to covert to an `Int` and back to a `String`) in `Ghost`.

Comment: Sorry it still didn't work :/ I did as you said and implemented onTouch etc, but i just had it log to LogCat to see if that worked but it still isn't doing it. Sorry for all the questions but im truly at a loss of what im doing wrong after near weeks of trying. I updated the code in the main post to show the changes I made

Comment: Having looked at the code some more, I would change `Panel` so that it extends `ViewGroup` and override `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Remove the `View.OnTouchListener` from `Ghost`.  Use `Panel` to keep/access the `Ghost` hitrect depending on whether you want it permanently or only when screen is touched (one `Ghost` could be done on each touch but if you have many it may take time to process through them all which will lag the UI thread).  You may need to run a background thread from `Panel` to keep track of each `Ghost` location anyway.